# RemoteMediaPlayer not loading media from url

Tags: android, google-cast

So I'm trying to play an mp3 from a url on an android tv and whenever I try to create a media object, an unknown error is thrown with the following footprint in the debugger.

```
{statusCode=unknown status code: 2001, resolution=null}
```

Here is how I'm currently trying to create the MediaInfo object:

```
MediaMetadata mediaMetadata = new MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MUSIC_TRACK);
    mediaMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, songName);
MediaInfo mediaInfo = new MediaInfo.Builder(songUrl)
    .setContentType("audio/mpeg")
    .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED)
    .setMetadata(mediaMetadata)
    .build();
```

Where the songUrl points to an mp3 stored on an external server.

This is how I'm creating the MediaPlayer object:

```
try {
        mRemoteMediaPlayer.load(mApiClient, mediaInfo, true)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<RemoteMediaPlayer.MediaChannelResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(RemoteMediaPlayer.MediaChannelResult mediaChannelResult) {
                        if (mediaChannelResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                            Log.d("done loading song", "");

                            mSongIsLoaded = true;
                        } else {
                            Log.d("", "failed to load");
                        }
                    }
                });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please post the full stack trace and where the error happens

Comment: There is no exception thrown. I had to view the value of mediaChannelResult in the debugger and the value was stored in a status field.

Comment: If you debug this code, does it reach the catch Exception block ? If it does, I need to see what that e.printStackTrace() says.

Comment: It doesn't reach the catch block.

Comment: And do you see your own logs "done loading song" / "failed to load" ?

Comment: yes it gets to failed to load.

Comment: The error 2001 means an invalid request; there is nothing particularly wrong with the way you are constructing your MediaInfo, that is fine (as long as the values for the fields you are populating are all valid values. The load command by itself is also fine so you need to make sure that mApiClient is valid and that media channel has been established, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> [2001 Status code indicates that an invalid request was made](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/CastStatusCodes)

Here is a list of all the relevant status codes:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/CastStatusCodes

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, turns out the cast application hadn't been launched. I put this code prior to loading media.

```
try {
        Cast.CastApi.launchApplication(mApiClient, Id, false)
        .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Cast.ApplicationConnectionResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(Cast.ApplicationConnectionResult applicationConnectionResult) {
                Status status = applicationConnectionResult.getStatus();
                if( status.isSuccess() ) {
                    load(media);
                }else{
                    Log.v(TAG, ""+applicationConnectionResult.getStatus().getStatusCode());
                }
            }
        });         
    } catch( Exception e ) {
        Log.v(TAG, "failed:"+e.getMessage());
    }
```

the load(media) method is identical to the code in your original question